# External CSS not working in HTML in Python project

Tags: python, html, css, django

I replaced `<style>` tag in `base.html` with an external CSS file. In `base.html` there is a menu which links to different HTML pages. When I click on any menu item, the page is loading but not CSS.

I tried using `<link>` tag in `homealter.html` for CSS to work, but it doesn't work.

base.html

```
<link href="../static/css/base_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="menu">
    <table>
        <tr>
            {% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}
            <td class="{% if url_name == 'home' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Resource Wise Analysis</a></td>
            <td class="{% if url_name == 'homealter' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{% url 'homealter' %}">Land Distance Analysis</a></td>
            <td class="{% if url_name == 'graphsone' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{% url 'graphsone' %}">Water Type Based Analysis</a></td>
            <td class="{% if url_name == 'graphstwo' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{% url 'graphstwo' %}">Land Distance Analysis</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></td>
            {% endwith %}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
{% block mains %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

homealter.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block mains %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="../static/css/base_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="contnt">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Land Size</th>
    <th>Land Distances Count</th>
    <!--<th>Details</th>-->
</tr>
{% for index, row in yeye.iterrows %}
<tr>
    <td><p>{{index}}</p></td>
    <td>{{row.Distance}}</td>
    <!--<td><a href="{% url 'yearwise' index %}">View Details</a></td>-->
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
<img src="{% static 'images/im1.jpg' %}">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

It worked earlier because there was internal CSS in `base.html`. I need `base_style.css` to work whenever menu items are selected i.e., in other pages as well.

Comment: where do you add `<link>` ? When you open page in browser and use Ctrl+U to see source code - do you see this link in HTML ? Copy this link from HTML and open in new card in browser - is it loading ?

Comment: I added `<link>` in div and also at the top, I also created a body tag, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: I don't see `<link>` in `<div>`. I see only one link to "../static/css/base_style.css" but it is not external link. Or maybe you mean external folder on disk - browser doesn't have access to external folders on disk for security reason.

Comment: In `homealter.html`, `<link>` is not working, and I removed it. I'll add it again.

Comment: to resolve problem you have to show code which you run and full errors which you get.

Comment: I tried using extends but it gives me an error like only one extends can be accepted.

Comment: why do you use relative url `../static/css/base_style.css` ? it can works on some pages and not works on another pages.  You should use absolute path. Besides if it is outside main folder then server may not send it - security reason - because someone could ask for file with passwords instead  css.

Comment: documentation for [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Both HTML files are in the same folder so it should work. It is a local project so no worries about the server. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll use the absolute path from now on.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is local server - all server has this restriction because one day you could use this local server as external server and someone could get all passwords or other private data. Django has special folders for images, css and other static files - you can't put CSS in the same folder as HTML. it is not server with static HTML or with pure PHP which let you put HTML, CSS, images in any folder and it will works.

Comment: HTML and CSS are in different folders only. I used static folder for CSS files. That's why they are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have it just in base.html, but the full path (not relative):

```
<link href="/static/css/base_style.css"...
```

or better:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/base_style.css' %}"...
```